# Is there a word that means "help someone with X", but without the implication that you're also helping with X?

Tags: word-request, idiom-request

When you use the phrase "help him with X" or any other similar phrase, you also imply that you're also doing the same thing and you're receiving help from another person, but what if you're not? What phrase would you use then? Let's say you said "Albert helped him restrain Robert", but only Albert was restraining him, while you were trying to feed him medicine, what phrase or word would you use to say that Albert restraining Robert was an act of help. You can just say he restrained him, but you can't also add the idea that he was helping you without making the implication that you were also restraining him.

For example:

Albert was ____ with restraining him while I was trying to feed him medicine.

Comment: *Dealing*, *tasked*, *preoccupied*? *Responsible for*? *...doing the restraining, while...*?

Comment: But they don't imply that he was "helping" me. The problem is that as soon as you use a word like "help" it also comes with the implication I was helping with restraining Robert.

Comment: (a) They do imply that, sort of, by virtue of *restraining*'s being a more peripheral sort of action, and (b) it doesn't necessarily. *He was helping me with X while I was doing Y* can be used to say he was doing X, and thereby helping me, while I was doing Y. Your question as written is somewhat unclear/tangled. Do wait for an actual answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rephrase

> Albert helped him restrain Robert

as

> Albert helped him by restraining Robert

which shows that Albert was providing help with a different task, that they were not *both* restraining Robert.